# What is the meaning of the Joke?

Tags: word-meaning, jokes

What is the meaning of the Joke?

> Hey, did you hear about the Jack who locked his keys in the car and
>   he used coat hanger to get his family out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logical interpretation of a situation, and is not about learning English.

Comment: What is your language-related question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jack's family was inside the car. They could have opened the car door from the inside, so there was no need to use a coat hanger to force the door open.

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of the kind of generic joke intended to make fun of people of a particular ethnicity, country, religion, appearance, behavior, or anything else you want to disparage.

For example, suppose you have a prejudice against people who drink tea.  In this joke you would substitute "tea-drinker" for "Jack", to show how idiotic you think they are:

> Q: How many [tea-drinkers] does it take to change a light bulb?
>   A: Three -- one to stand on a chair and hold the bulb and the other two to spin the chair.

I used to hear those kind of jokes more often when I was younger, but I'm not sure if I don't hear them now because society has lost tolerance for such things, or because it's juvenile humor that adults don't find very funny.

Comment: This is the correct answer as cited [here](http://jokstop.com/143)